# MySQL UDF Plugin cannot Execute Shell Commands (with system() or execl())

Tags: python, mysql, c, plugins, triggers

I am running a User Defined Function plugin for MySQL. The program works fine except for when you do a system call. I need to do a system call in order to call a Python3 script!
All of the system calls that I do, with system() or execl(), all return -1 and fail.

Does anybody know how to make my C library MySQL UDF plugin able to execute shell commands? We are completely stuck with this, thanks!

Here is the C code that I a having issues with:

```
  # Written in C Language

  #include <string.h>
  #include <stdio.h>

  #include <mysql.h>

  bool udf_callpython_init(UDF_INIT *initid, UDF_ARGS *args, char *message) {

      // None of these work...
      int systemResult = system("echo hello");
      //int systemResult = execl("/bin/bash", "bash", "-c", "echo hello again...", (char *) NULL);    
      //int systemResult = execl("/bin/ls", "ls", "-l", (char*)0);
      //int systemResult = system("python3 python_script.py")

      char str[100];
      sprintf(str, "%d", systemResult);
      strcpy(message, str);

      return 1;
  }

  char* udf_callpython(UDF_INIT *initid, UDF_ARGS *args,
          char *result, unsigned long *length, 
          char *is_null, char *error) {     

      system("echo test > does_not_work.txt");

      strcpy(result, "Hello, World!");
      *length = strlen(result);

      return result;
  }
```

This is how I compiled this code:

```
  gcc -o udf_callpython.so udf_callpython.c -I/usr/include/mysql/ -L/usr/include/mysql/ -shared -fPIC
```

I then copy that .so library file to mysql's plugin directory:

```
  sudo cp udf_callpython.so /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/
```

I then create the function in MySQL like this:

```
  CREATE FUNCTION udf_callpython RETURNS STRING SONAME "udf_callpython.so";
```

I then have this procedure to call this UDF:

```
  DELIMITER $$
  $$
  USE test_db
  $$
  CREATE PROCEDURE example_insert_proc()
  BEGIN

  DECLARE result VARCHAR(255);
  SET result = udf_callpython();

  END;$$
  DELIMITER ;
```

Then, on the output, you will see -1:

```
  mysql> CALL example_insert_proc();
  ERROR 1123 (HY000): Can't initialize function 'udf_callpython'; -1
```

(EDIT:)
I found that the errno is 13, which is Permission denied.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out this issue! I am answering this is case anybody else has the same problem...

I disabled AppArmor (Ubuntu 20.04):

```
  sudo systemctl disable apparmor
  sudo reboot now
```

If you then rerun the stored procedure, the system() call succeeds:

```
  mysql> CALL example_insert_proc();
  ERROR 1123 (HY000): Can't initialize function 'udf_callpython'; 0
  mysql>
```